# Optimize query for mysql and php

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have table with fields like id,name and values like (1,"sony,nokia,htc"),(2,"sony")(3,"Samsung").I fetch the records but my logic goes longer than my expection.I want to exlode name if it contains "," and fetch unique records.My result will look like

```
Name array will be { 0 =>"sony",1=>"HTC",2=>"Nokia"}.My dummy logic is here (This is incomplete not working properly.)
<?php 
$row = array("sony,htc,nokia","htc","sony");
    foreach ($row as $key => $valuek) {
                 if(strpos($valuek['value'], ",") !== false)
                 {
                  $str[] = explode(",",$valuek['value'] )
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $valuek['value']?>"><?php echo $valuek['value']?></option>
                   <?php 
                 }

            ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $valuek['value']?>"><?php echo $valuek['value']?></option>
       <?php  } $i++;}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t need to do explode that

At the start where you get all your data and stored in array you can just used `array_unique()`

```
$row = array("sony,htc,nokia","htc","sony"); // all fetch data from db.


 $row = implode(',',$row); // first convert the array -> strings
 $row = explode(',',$row); // then return back to array and you can now use array_unique
 $row = array_unique($row);  // this will filter all data with uniqueness and drop some data that have same value
```

then you can use this to loop the data on.

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($row)){
     echo '<option value="'.$row[$i].'">'.$row[$i].'</option>';
 }
```

this will make your code shorter and easy to manage..

Comment: Thanks but as for my knowledge array_unique is not working in this condition.I think i have to explode array elements.Check your code .

Comment: It display results in this formate :Array ( [0] => sony,htc,nokia [1] => htc [2] => sony )